# Can't seem to access an old external/USB hdd

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive

*I'll preface this with the disclaimer that I am mediocre at best with all things Linux. I've got multiple-year stints with Ubuntu as my only OS in the past, but I've generally had to rely on step-by-step guides on anything involving the terminal without really being able to grasp what I was actually doing, or why something works.*

Alright, here's the skinny: I've got an old Maxtor OneTouch USB HDD that has a lot of my creative works locked up within. I *think* it "stopped working" about 6 years ago while being used on a windows machine. (I say "stopped working" because I simply cannot recall what the issue was.)

So I've dusted it off, plugged'er into this little NUC that I've got running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Nothing happens when I turn it on. So opening up the dreaded terminal I've tried the following sorcery:

```bsh
sudo fdisk -l
```

Which spat out... well, a lot. But the pertinent bit I think is as follows:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 189.9 GiB, 203927060480 bytes, 398295040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6851e014
```

Now, the drive I'm trying to access is 200 Gb. So maaaaybe this is what I'm after? And I saw that little nugget about DOS. That's a windows thing right? Right?! Alright, I shall attempt to fiddle more with this by hammering in:

```bsh
sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt
```

But alas, it spat this nonsense back at me:

```
mount: /mnt: can't read superblock on /dev/sdb.
```

Alright, so maybe that wasn't what I wanted. A little more googling lead me to thing punching this in was a good idea:

```bsh
sudo lsusb
```

And... HUZZAH!! I can see the droid, er... DRIVE I'm looking for! :

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 258a:1006  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c07e Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0d49:7000 Maxtor OneTouch
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

There it is! There it is!! I can almost taste it.

> ```
> Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0d49:7000 Maxtor OneTouch
> ```

That is what I want. I wanna be inside of it.. Er, you know what I mean.

So here is the impasse I sit at. I'm so deep in these confounding weeds that I don't even know what I should be asking the google machine how to do.

If anyone out in the aether can tell me what I need to do, I would be eternally grateful. Hell, if you can get me into this drive, I will sing you a song about, um.. I dunno. Penguins? Yes, Penguins. Murderous little penguins.

Again, thanks a bazillion to anyone who can offer some insight.

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl -f` as you plug in the USB. Read `man fsck fsck.vfat`.

Comment: Also read `man -a mount fstab`

Comment: dmesg output after you try to mount should tell you what it happening. Also lsblk -fi or blkid will give you details on the filesystems on your disk.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are trying to mount the disk instead of the partition.

```
user@server:~$ sudo mount /dev/sde /mnt/test/
mount: /mnt/test: can't read superblock on /dev/sde.
```

Using `lsblk`, you can see the block devices and the partitions identified within.

```
user@server:~$ lsblk  /dev/sde
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sde      8:64   0 465.8G  0 disk
└─sde1   8:65   0 465.8G  0 part
user@server:~$
```

You can see the recognized partition types using `lsblk -f`

```
user@server:$ lsblk -f /dev/sde
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL    UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sde
└─sde1 exfat  Untitled 5EDC-05D5                             465.8G     0% /mnt/test
user@server:$
```

Mount of the partition is successful in this case.

```
user@server:$ sudo mount /dev/sde1 /mnt/test/
user@server:$ lsblk  /dev/sde
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sde      8:64   0 465.8G  0 disk
└─sde1   8:65   0 465.8G  0 part /mnt/test
user@server:$
```